# Decide which SignalR Hub to connect to

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I'm confused about the rule of deciding which **Hub** to connect or not using **SignalR**.

In javascript, if I write `$.connection.hub.start()`, and say I have two Hubs(hub1 and hub2), then which hub gets connected? Or are they are both connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both will be connected. If you check documentation: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#multiplehubs

> - You can define multiple Hub classes in an application. When you do that, the connection is shared but groups are separate:
>
> All clients will use the same URL to establish a SignalR connection with your service ("/signalr" or your custom URL if you specified one), and that connection is used for all Hubs defined by the service.
>
> There is no performance difference for multiple Hubs compared to defining all Hub functionality in a single class.
>
> - All Hubs get the same HTTP request  information.
>
> Since all Hubs share the same connection, the only HTTP request information that the server gets is what comes in the original HTTP request that establishes the SignalR connection. If you use the connection request to pass information from the client to the server by specifying a query string, you can't provide different query strings to different Hubs. All Hubs will receive the same information.

Answer (score 0):

I found following stuff from the client js guide. " the presence of a client method on a Hub's proxy is what tells SignalR to trigger the OnConnected event"

> Note: Normally you register event handlers before calling the start method to establish the connection. If you want to register some event handlers after establishing the connection, you can do that, but you must register at least one of your event handler(s) before calling the start method. One reason for this is that there can be many Hubs in an application, but you wouldn't want to trigger the OnConnected event on every Hub if you are only going to use to one of them. When the connection is established, the presence of a client method on a Hub's proxy is what tells SignalR to trigger the OnConnected event. If you don't register any event handlers before calling the start method, you will be able to invoke methods on the Hub, but the Hub's OnConnected method won't be called and no client methods will be invoked from the server.